# Launch 2 celery processes via cron

Tags: bash, cron

I'm trying to chain some commands to periodically check/launch two processes via `cron` (I'm on a shared host, can't change things around). After a lot of googling around, all the things I've done don't work properly:

Trying to launch them separately in two cron jobs cascades and crushes the server (maybe because the `grep` command doesn't manage to catch the search words because they are parameters, I don't understand):

```
ps -fu $USER | grep celeryd >/dev/null || $HOME/python27/bin/python $HOME/utilities/manage.py celeryd -E -B --concurrency=1
ps -fu $USER | grep celerycam >/dev/null || $HOME/python27/bin/python $HOME/utilities/manage.py celerycam
```

And these other variants where I try to launch the processes together on the same `cron`, launch only the first process:

```
ps -u $USER | grep python >/dev/null || $HOME/python27/bin/python $HOME/utilities/manage.py celeryd -E -B --concurrency=1 & $HOME/python27/bin/python $HOME/utilities/manage.py celerycam &

ps -u $USER | grep python >/dev/null || ( $HOME/python27/bin/python $HOME/utilities/manage.py celeryd -E -B --concurrency=1 & $HOME/python27/bin/python $HOME/utilities/manage.py celerycam; )

ps -u $USER | grep python >/dev/null || ( $HOME/python27/bin/python $HOME/utilities/manage.py celeryd -E -B --concurrency=1; ) sleep 30s; ( $HOME/python27/bin/python $HOME/utilities/manage.py celerycam; )
```

I gave up trying to use grep and took advantage of the `--pidfile` option of the `celery worker`; `celerycam` doesn't allow multiple instances so I don't need any `grep` there to check for it:

```
$HOME/python27/bin/python $HOME/utilities/manage.py celery worker -E -B --concurrency=1 --pidfile=worker.pid
$HOME/python27/bin/python $HOME/utilities/manage.py celerycam
```

Comment: Have you try to run your celery processes in screen/tmux sessions, that might be more easier to manage than cron jobs

Comment: @number5 yes screen was the solution I used before, but they either get automatically axed by my host after an amount of time or the server restarts too often (2,3 times during the day)

Comment: Yep I understand the pain to work in shared hosting env (Dream****), the ultimate solution might be to switch to some real VPS... (I know sometime it not an option either)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`$USER` is not set in most crons. Luckily `ps -u` without a username defaults to the present user (which is the user from which cron is running for). However your grep has quite a high chance to match the grep *itself* as well as the celery processes. You can clean that issue up with a sneaky `grep '[c]elery'`. This will match processes with names/arguments that contain celery only (and not the grep which has argument [c]elery). The other issue I can see is that because you run the program with a giant path to manage.py you may be missing the "celery" part in your `ps` output. That can be remedied by adding more verbosity to the output of ps with the `-w` flag (the more of them there are the more verbose it becomes). So The suggested fix is:

```
ps fwwwu | grep '[c]eleryd' >/dev/null || $HOME/python27/bin/python $HOME/utilities/manage.py celeryd -E -B --concurrency=1
ps fwwwu  | grep '[c]elerycam' >/dev/null || $HOME/python27/bin/python $HOME/utilities/manage.py celerycam
```

**EDIT:** Removed the extraneous dash from the ps arguments above and added `pgrep` as a viable alternative.

Alternatively you can also make use of two other commands `pidof` and `pgrep` to get the process ids of running processes. I think in this instance (if your username is fred) you can replace the `ps` command with:

```
pgrep -fu fred celeryd
```

to achieve similar results.

**EDIT 2:** Add single quotes around '[c]elery' to stop shell globbing (the directory where the cron is ran from (the users $HOME) may contain a file that is called celery.

Comment: Thanks for your great explanation, it's much clear for me now what happens there. Unfortunately ps returns this error: "Warning: bad syntax, perhaps a bogus '-'?". Could be some version related issues?

Comment: Ah sorry that's a habbit I've never managed to shake, just use `ps fwwwu` (other 'flavors' of unix start ps arguments with a dash and I started on those - I just put the dash in by habbit :)

Comment: both "ps fwwwu" and "ps -fwwwu $USER" (with fwwu or fwwwu) work in the shell, but neither work with cron. I think cron might be limited in some way. Anyway thank you very much :)

Comment: Either that could be the $PATH does not include the directory where ps is _or_ you could add the user to filter for with 'ps -fwwwwu fred' if the username is fred. I'll update the answer to give some alternative solutions.